# C++ Enum in struct error for definition

Tags: c++, struct, enums

Hello im a newbie from C++.
For a my project i need to use a enum value similar C# example.

My Struct

```
struct Rows
{
    string name;
    bool primaryKey;
    int lenght;
    string defined;
    MyLDC::Attributes attrib;
    bool Nullable;
    bool AutoIncrement;
    string comment;

};
Rows rw;
Rows* row = &rw;
```

MyLDC::Attributes

```
enum Attributes
{
    _BINARY = 0x26,
    _UNSIGNED = 0x27
};
```

My Example function

```
void MyLDC::CreateTable(string tablename,string primaryKey)
{

    //Simple Row Implementation
    row->name = "Example Row";
    row->AutoIncrement = true;
    row->primaryKey = true;
    row->comment = "Example Row";

    row->attrib = Attributes::_UNSIGNED;
```

I get error on row->attrib = Attributes::_UNSIGNED;

no have idea for this error.
who are the correct solution?

Comment: And *what* error do you get? Please include the full error, complete and unedited, in the question body.

Comment: Unrelated to your error, symbol names starting with an underscore and followed by an upper-case letter are reserved for the implementation (compiler and standard library). See e.g. [this old SO answer for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/440558).

Comment: Error: Attributes' is not a class or namespace|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> enum Attributes
> {
>     _BINARY = 0x26,
>     _UNSIGNED = 0x27
> };
> ...
> row->attrib = Attributes::_UNSIGNED;
> ```

My psychic debugging powers ;) tell me that the problem is that the `_UNSIGNED` symbol is not under the scope of `Attributes`, so you should be able to do:

```
row->attrib = _UNSIGNED;
```

For scoped enums you may want to use C++11's `enum class`.

**P.S.** Note also that `_Upper` (underscore followed by uppercase letter) names are *reserved* for implementations, and should not be used in your code.

Comment: @JoeMartiniello: Glad to be of some help. I've been there before as well :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't get. It seems to be working in my case: http://ideone.com/4KyrH6 What different I am doing?